# .net service: external application's startup event

Tags: .net, events, service

I am looking for an event in my service that is fired on startup of an external application,
I do not constantly want to scan the running applications, but rather looking for an event that is triggered on an application's startup.

Thank you

Comment: Who/what is starting the application? Be aware that services run in a separate session from any user sessions and communicating between the sessions generally requires you to have running code in both.

Comment: Im trying to program a service to detect if another service is started